# When using map over onClick handler the inner function always gets the last element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a nested JSX component with a mapping function with an inner mapping function:

```
{steps.map(({
    step_id: stepId,
    step_name: stepName
}) => (
    <TableRow key={stepId}>
    (...)
    {steps.map(
      ({ step_id: id, name }) => (
          {stepId} // <- rendering the stepId leads to list of different numbers
          <MenuItem
            key={id}
            onClick={() => {
              this.addNeededStep(stepId, id); // <- stepId is ALWAYS the last in the list
              this.closeNeededStepSelector();
          }}
          >
            {name}
          </MenuItem>)
      )}
    </TableRow>
))}
```

Now, when the onClick handler is clicked the `addNeededStep` function always receive the last `stepId` of the `steps`.

I expect it to be the stepId as specified on line 2 (`step_id: stepId`). Why does this happen? And how can I fix it?

What I tried is using bind to bind the stepId because I thought it was a JavaScript issue with enclosed functions losing their outer scope, but that did not help.

Comment: Isn't it weird that your map callback is also performing a map on the same steps array ?

Comment: You are calling the function after all the mapping has ended leaving just the last value. If you want to use it you need to pass is as a prop to each map instance.

Also, we can't see your source over which you map, but it seems odd that you are mapping over same thing in a nested case `steps.map`.

Comment: @nubinub why is that weird?

Comment: @Vrle It creates 20 rows or so for every step id... So if you print the row I see stepId 1 till 20, but if I call the onClick handler it always has the last value (even if another stepId is displayed). Do I understand correctly that JavaScript is not creating a proper closure in the onClick handler where the environment is captured?

Comment: @nubinub. If stepId is 1 till 5 it creates a list like:

`[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`.

Comment: I just can't see the use case where it's important to map the steps array just because you need that second map to be performed `steps.length` times. But anyway guess you can just store the stepId into a scoped constant like `const currentStepId = stepId;` to avoid issue pointed out by @vrle. Although be aware that for performance reason this is bad practice to use arrow functions within map or other iterations process, you should lookup some [memoize like package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoize)

Comment: The use case is displaying a list of steps, and every step can have dependencies which are themselves steps. So every row also displays the list to add a dependency, and when you add a dependency I need to know which row was clicked. It is more efficient to generate the nested list only once indeed so I will look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work perfectly fine the way you wrote it, at least with this simple example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGQadd).  Can you provide more of your source code, maybe something interferring with the steps values ?

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const test = [{elem:1},{elem:2},{elem:3},{elem:4},{elem:5}]
    return (
      <div>
        {
          test.map(({elem: initElem}) => 
            test.map(elem => {
              return (
                <div onClick={() => { alert(initElem);} }>
                  {initElem}                   
                </div>
              );
            })
          )

        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately assigning stepId to a new variable named currentStepId and then returning the JSX does does not solve the problem. The onClick handler keeps referring to the last id.

Comment: I try to put it in a prop

Comment: This is the last project I will use plain React for. Reagent + ClojureScript is so much nicer. http://reagent-project.github.io/. All these problems are non-existent.

Comment: It seems to works pretty fine even without the scoped const. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGQadd

Comment: Thanks @nubinub for the effort. Strange, maybe in my specific code it was different. What did work was extracting the NeededStepSelector in a separate component. I passed the `addNeededStep` function, `steps` and the `stepId` as props. I.e. `<NeededStepSelector stepId={stepId} steps={steps} addNeededStep={(id, neededId) => this.addNeededStep(id, neededId)} />`. That was the only thing that did work in my case. Creating a separate prop also increased performance.

Comment: Perhaps because my component was much larger React decided to render in a different order? For now the problem is gone. The solution was to create a new component as pass the function and stepId as props. Although I don't know the specific reason why it failed in my case (especially since your example works fine), I will accept your answer. Thanks!